# How do I give Internal Users visibility to the 'Community Members' Related List on Accounts?

Tags: community, account, related-list, permission-sets

I need to give a certain group of internal users Read-Only access to each Account's Community Members.   Ideally, I'd like to use a Permission Set to do this.

Although I've added the 'Community Members' related list to the correct Account page layout, my internal users still can't see it.   I don't see any Object or System permissions on the Profile level--or available in Permission Sets--to expose 'Community Members'.

I know that it's possible in my org, because users with other Profiles can see the related list.

For business reasons, I can't assign these users to that other Profile--and need to figure out how to do it with their existing one.

What permission am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Community members are setup as Contacts / Person Accounts (Contacts).

These members all have an account relationship and an additional User record with lookups to both account and contact records.  You can learn more via Trailhead:
[Set Up a Portal](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/insurance-for-financial-services-cloud-admin-essentials/set-up-a-portal-for-independent-insurance-agents)

Which object is your related list pointing to? Contacts or Users? Whichever one it is, grant object level access, provide any sharing rules for record level access (depending on your OWD), and then grant field level access to all the fields referenced in the related list.

Answer (score 0):

If they are not admin they will not inherently be able to view all users and that is was the Community Member related list is displaying. Since that cannot be set at the object level you must add the System Permission, "View All Users". You can set this on the user's profile (not recommended) or create a permission set and assign it to the necessary users.

[image]